# JTable preferred size with header?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I'm trying to set a JScrollPane to the size of the JTable, just so I can get the column headers but I don't want it to be scrollable (nor let the JScrollPane take up unnecessary screen real estate). How can I get the preferred dimensions of the JTable with the column headers, so I can set the JScrollPane's preferred dimensions to it?

Comment: You can effect the amount of space a JScrollPane wants by chaining the value returned by [getPreferredScrollableViewportSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Scrollable.html#getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()) of the JTable. You can set the table to auto sizing, which will force the table to only occupy the available horizontal space of the JTable, see [setAutoResizeMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode(int))

Comment: The preferredSize of the JTable is what is used by the JScrollPane to display the table header and make decisions about whether to show the scroll bars or not

Comment: What about vertical space? I want to limit the vertical JScrollPane space to just the JTable's height.

Comment: `JTable#getPreferredSize`.  You could try feeding the information from `getPreferredSize` through the `JTable`'s `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize`, this will limit the `JScrollPane`'s viewable area to the preferable size of the `JTable`, but it might also present other issues...

Answer (score 0):

```
    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
    pane .setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

you can do the same for horizontal.  Generally setting them to as needed is preferred.

Comment: Okay, you've hidden the scroll bar, this won't prevent the table/header from expanding beyond the vertical bounds of the scroll pane...

Comment: yeah I've just tried this and that is exactly what happened. I'll play with your solutions next...